# Passport not exposing login() function on request

Tags: node.js, passport.js

In the code below, when I log the request object (`console.log('req', req)`), I am unable to locate the login() method in the request. Why isn't the login method available on the request here?

```
// Login User
app.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('local', {}, (err, user, info) => {
        console.log('req', req)

        if (err) throw err
        if (!user) console.log('User does not exist...')
        if (user) {
            console.log('user confirmed')
            req.logIn(user, next)
        }
    })(req, res, next);
    res.send('User logged in...')
});
```

middleware...

```
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors({ origin: ["http://localhost:3000", "http://localhost:3030"], credentials: true }))
app.use(session({
    name: 'bucketbadge:sess',
    secret: 'secretcat',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { secure: false }
}))

app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())

require('./config/passport-setup')
```

passport-setup.js...

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy((username, password, done) => {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, (err, user) => {
        console.log('user in User.findOne', user)
        if (err) throw err;
        if (!user) return done(null, false);
        bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, result) => {
            if (err) throw err
            if (result === true) {
                console.log('user:', user)
                return done(null, user);
            } else {
                return done(null, false);
            }
        })
    });
}
));

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    console.log('user.id @ serializeUser:', user.id)
    done(null, user.id)
})

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    console.log('deserialize user:', id)

    User.findById(id, (err, user) => {
        done(err, user.id)
    });
});
```

The documentation per Passport JS...

Passport exposes a `login()` function on req `(also aliased as logIn())` that can be used to establish a login session.

```
req.login(user, function(err) {
  if (err) { return next(err); }
  return res.redirect('/users/' + req.user.username);
});
```

When the login operation completes, the user will be assigned to `req.user.`

**Note:**
`passport.authenticate()` middleware invokes `req.login()` automatically. This function is primarily used when users sign up, during which `req.login()` can be invoked to automatically log in to the newly registered user.

Shouldn't the `login()` method be available in the request within `passport.authenticate()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you're assuming too much about what `console.log()` is going to show you. For instance:

```
class Test {
    classMethod() { }
}
let object = new Test()
object.instanceMethod = () => { }

console.log(object)

//output
Test { instanceMethod: [Function (anonymous)] }  // no "classMethod" property here.
```

Or:

```
var object = {
    enumerable: "enumerable property"
}
Object.defineProperty(object, "nonenumerable", {
    value: "non-enumerable property",
    enumerable: false
})
console.log(object)

// output
{ enumerable: 'enumerable property' }  // no "nonenumerable" property here.
```

Thses are just a couple simple examples to illustrate the point. I would assume you agree that in both cases, the `classMethod` and `nonenumerable` properties are actually available on the objects that are output.

In your case, it turns out the `login` method is not actually defined on the `req` object itself - but somewhere on its prototype chain.

```
passport.authenticate('jwt', function (error, payload, info) {
  console.log("login" in req)
  console.log(req.hasOwnProperty("login"))
  console.log(findOwningObject(req, "login"))
  // ...
})

function findOwningObject(object, key) {
  if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    return object
  }

  var proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(object)
  if (!proto) throw new Error("Property not found")
  return findOwningObject(proto, key)
}

// output
true          // login property is available on req?
false         // login property is owned by req?
Readable {    // owning object for login.
  setTimeout: [Function: setTimeout],
  _read: [Function: _read],
  destroy: [Function: destroy],
  _addHeaderLines: [Function: _addHeaderLines],
  _addHeaderLine: [Function: _addHeaderLine],
  _dump: [Function: _dump],
  logIn: [Function (anonymous)],
  login: [Function (anonymous)],
  logOut: [Function (anonymous)],
  logout: [Function (anonymous)],
  isAuthenticated: [Function (anonymous)],
  isUnauthenticated: [Function (anonymous)]
}
```

Comment: Thank you, IAmDranged... you are correct about my expectations from console.log(), and this perfectly answers my question. Much appreciated.